# Steps to download and install vpnc on centos

Tags: linux, centos, vpn

all I'm trying to install vpnc on centos. But getting following errors

```
[root@mahesh mparte]# yum install -y vpnc
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Waiting for process with pid 7137 to finish.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Tue 08 Dec 2020 09:11:17 GMT.
No match for argument: vpnc
Error: Unable to find a match: vpnc
```

Have tried this too `yum --enablerepo="epel" install vpnc`, says package not found

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" list available | grep vpnc
yum --enablerepo=epel info vpnc-script.noarch

Name         : vpnc-script
Version      : 20171004
Release      : 6.git6f87b0f.el8
Architecture : noarch
Size         : 16 k
Source       : vpnc-script-20171004-6.git6f87b0f.el8.src.rpm
Repository   : epel
Summary      : Routing setup script for vpnc and openconnect
URL          : http://git.infradead.org/users/dwmw2/vpnc-scripts.git/
License      : GPLv2+
Description  : This script sets up routing for VPN connectivity, when invoked by vpnc
             : or openconnect.
```

Comment: Your output shows the name of the package is `vpnc-script`, so it would be installed with `yum --enablerepo=epel install vpnc-script`.

Comment: My Centos VM on Virtual Box is showing blank screen, was working fine yesterday. But I believe this should work ? yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=epel install vpnc   I need to install vpnc. Any idea why the virtual box keeps showing blank screen , I always go mad, when it does

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use RedHat software you need to purchase a support licence:

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

Otherwise use CentOS or some other distribution.

Comment: I'm using CentOS

Comment: Please add the list of your repositories to the question